# Visual Studio 2013 post build event shows always explorer

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, post-build-event

I wanted to make some post build stuff in my project (VisualC++), which involves copying some files to output directory. Mostly they are resource files like icons and xml/css. The problem is, that it opens after every build the explorer no matter what. I tried to check that if the copyable stuff resides in the target folder and if yes, then do not copy the files, but it seems to ignore me. Here is my post build event:

```
IF NOT EXIST $(OutDir)fonts\uni05_53.ttf
(
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)uni05_53.ttf" "$(OutDir)fonts\" /Y /I
)

IF NOT EXIST $(OutDir)data\favicon.ico
(
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)data\favicon.ico" "$(OutDir)images\" /Y /I
)

IF NOT EXIST $(OutDir)layout\warlockgui.css
(
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)layout\warlockgui.css" "$(OutDir)layout\" /Y /I
)

IF NOT EXIST $(OutDir)layout\warlockgui.xml
(
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)layout\warlockgui.xml" "$(OutDir)layout\" /Y /I
)
```

Even when I specified the date with /D switch, it opens the explorer on the project root every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong.  Opening parentheses must be on the same line since batch is parsed line by line.  Otherwise the if statement will do nothing because it does not know that it should contain the following lines.

```
IF NOT EXIST "$(OutDir)fonts\uni05_53.ttf" (
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)uni05_53.ttf" "$(OutDir)fonts\" /Y /I
)

IF NOT EXIST "$(OutDir)data\favicon.ico" (
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)data\favicon.ico" "$(OutDir)images\" /Y /I
)

IF NOT EXIST "$(OutDir)layout\warlockgui.css" (
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)layout\warlockgui.css" "$(OutDir)layout\" /Y /I
)

IF NOT EXIST "$(OutDir)layout\warlockgui.xml" (
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)layout\warlockgui.xml" "$(OutDir)layout\" /Y /I
)
```

Comment: thanks, but for some strange reason it fires also the explorer :/